# shipping charges are applying only for one product

Tags: shipping, static-block, phtml

In cart page left bottom ,  we have a feature of finding shipping charges using this file code : `app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`

[image]

I need the same feature inside table in cart page.

[image]

cart page file : `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` file.

we are using following code. but its working only for 1st product. for 1st product, its taking shipping charge as half of the total shipping charge. but this is wrong. it should give shipping charge per product.

than in **default.phtm**l file, i used this code :

```
<?php 
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_shipping')->setProductId($pId)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/shipping1.phtml')->tohtml(); 
?>
```

**cartcontroller.php** :

```
public function estimatePost1Action($productId)
    {
$zipcode   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode');

        // Update the cart's quote.
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $address = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        $address->setPostcode($zipcode)
                ->setCollectShippingrates(true);
        //$cart->save();

        // Find if our shipping has been included.
        $rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
                         ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
        $count=1;
        foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
        foreach ($carrier as $rate) {     

               $count=$count+1;
                $rate=$rate->getPrice();
                $i++;
            }
        }

        echo (int) $rate/$count;


        die;
}
```

**shipping.phtml** code

```
app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

<?php /** @var $this Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping */ ?>
<?php $pId=$this->getProductId();?>
<div class="shipping">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('') ?></h2>
    <div class="shipping-form">
       <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost') ?>" method="post" id="shipping-zip-form">

            <ul class="form-list">
            <div style="display:none">

               <li>
                    <label for="country"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
                    </div>

                </li>
            </div>

            <?php //if($this->getStateActive()): ?>
            <!--
                <li>
                    <label for="region_id"<?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" style="display:none;"<?php echo ($this->isStateProvinceRequired() ? ' class="validate-select"' : '') ?>>
                            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                        </select>
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                       //<![CDATA[
                           $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getEstimateRegionId() ?>");
                       //]]>
                       </script>
                       <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
                   </div>
                </li>
            -->
            <?php //endif; ?>
            <?php if($this->getCityActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="city"<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input class="input-text<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" id="city" type="text" name="estimate_city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateCity()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="postcode"<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('Check Delivery') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="postcode<?php echo $pId?>" name="estimate_postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimatePostcode()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <span id="costmsg<?php echo $pId?>"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buttons-set">
                 <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Check') ?>" id="delivery_button" onclick="checkshipping('<?php echo $pId?>')" class="button">
                 <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Check') ?>
                 </span></span></button>
            </div>

        </form>

        <!-- Pras -->
     <td>


    <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): 

     if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage()){
             echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage();
             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMyShipMessage();
        }

    endif; ?>   
    </td>   

    <!-- Pras end -->


        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>);
        //]]>
        </script>
        <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): ?>
        <form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost') ?>">
            <dl class="sp-methods11">
                <?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                            <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                               <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?>
                               <?php else: ?>
                                    <input name="estimate_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getCode()) ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                                    <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </label>
                               <?php endif ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <div style="display:none;">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>" class="button" name="do" 
                value="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

function checkshipping(pid){

    var zip=jQuery("#postcode"+pid).val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        method:'post',
        data: { 'zipcode': zip} ,
        url:'<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost1/', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(result,status,xhr){alert(result);
          //  jQuery("#costmsg"+pid).html('MP Per Product Shipping '+result);
            document.getElementById('costmsg'+pid).innerHTML='MP Per Product Shipping '+result;
        //print the message in a div or span
    },
        error: function(r,e){console.log(r.responseText);}
    });
}

            var coShippingMethodForm = new VarienForm('shipping-zip-form');
            var countriesWithOptionalZip = <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>;

            coShippingMethodForm.submit = function () {
                var country = $F('country');
                var optionalZip = false;

                for (i=0; i < countriesWithOptionalZip.length; i++) {
                    if (countriesWithOptionalZip[i] == country) {
                        optionalZip = true;
                    }
                }
                if (optionalZip) {
                    $('postcode').removeClassName('required-entry');
                }
                else {
                    $('postcode').addClassName('required-entry');
                }
                return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(coShippingMethodForm)();
            }   

        //]]>


        </script>





    </div>
</div>
```

ex: visit [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-flying-horse-wood-sticker.html) , [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-balloons.html)

Comment: please tell me why downvote? , so i can edit question & correct it.

Comment: Maybe people is downvoting because your constant edits

Comment: @RaulSanchez Thanks for your comment on my post.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you study the html rendered on your checkout page and also study the code in `shipping.phtml` and the html generated on your single product page.

If you render `shipping.phtml` directly into the single product page then you end up with a nested HTML `<form id="shipping-zip-form">` inside the outer product `<form id="product_addtocart_form">`

Maybe you already changed the template to remove the `<form id="shipping-zip-form">`

However the inline JavaScript generated by `shipping.phtml` outputs the JavaScript

```
var coShippingMethodForm = new VarienForm('shipping-zip-form');
```

So it is seeking an HTML DOM `<form id='shipping-zip-form'>` which you don't have. Furthermore that default JavaScript is also seeking to submit to the HTML `<form>` `action=""` attribute which you also don't have.

I recommend you either change the single product view layout to seperate the forms or re-write the javascript to submit to the correct URL `$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost')`.

BUT you really need to study how the shipping-zip form works on the checkout page: is it using ajax? what JS is needed to capture the returned ajax? what page is it trying to redirect to or reload? I recommend an ajax solution on the single product page.

So I'm afraid you have a lot of code to read and understand and possibly a chunk of work to get this functioning on the single product page. But don't be downheartend. You will be elated when it works.

Actually I think you should ditch `shipping.phtml` as a template and create a custom one `shipingestimatesingleproduct.phtml` or just rip essential phtml out of shipping.phtml, rewrite it, and stuff it into your `/catalog/product/view.phtml` file. In view.phtml you will need a reference to the `checkout/cart_shipping` block class

```
$shippingBlockClass = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_shipping');
```

so now you can call

```
$shippingBlockClass->isStateProvinceRequired();
```

from inside catalog/product/view.phtml and so on.

So if you don't understand those two lines of code then instead make shipingestimatesingleproduct.phtml and rewrite the HTML without a form and change the javascript to submit directly to

```
$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost')
```

But that may not be an ajax call. I think the controller that receives that URL will try to return a checkout page or 302 you to the basket.

Converting this to ajax is a whole other question (and beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer; seek an online tutorial instead or study the way Magento makes ajax calls).

In summary, shipping.pthml cannot be used as is; that code needs customised to function on the single product page.

Comment: you are absolutely right, need to learn lot of things for this , i will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"}}
```

To:

```
{{block type="checkout/cart_shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Now its displaying UI part, but functionailty is working. means if i click on "check" button, shipping charges are not working.

Comment: visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html) and click on "Buy Now" button you can see  2 "check" butttons,

one inside table, type"560043" and check its not giving shipping charges. but when we use the "check"

button present below, than it will work.

Comment: You would have to ajax the request that the button performs after a legitimate zip code is typed into that field.

Comment: can you please update the answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using correct syntax:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('delivery')->toHtml();  ?>
```

This should work but not sure what has happened on your case.

Here are things you can check:

1. Check if your cms block id is correct `delivery`
2. Check if your `core/template` is white listed as per magento's new security measures (go to `System > Permission > Block` and see if `core/template` listed there, otherwise just add your self)

If none of the above work, you can call your phtml from xml too, like this:

Open your `local.xml` if you have it, if you don't have it create one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_my_block" as="cms_my_block">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>delivery</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</default>
```

Now, call this block in your `cart.phtml` file

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_my_block'); ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry Buddy, It did't worked....

Comment: UI part is worked for me using another solution. visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html) and click on "Buy Now" button you can see  2 "check" butttons,

one inside table, type"560043" and check its not giving shipping charges. but when we use the "check"

button present below, than it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if the static block is contained in a folder that is referenced via a symlink.

At least with Magento 2 - this can cause the problem.

An easy way to diagnose this is to copy the files and folder paths without symlinks - and if it works you know the cause.

Comment: if i understood correctly, i have to copy the code and keep in correct files instead of using static blocks. is that i have to do ?